# vue-select allowing multiple duplicates

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-select

I'm dynamically creating vue-select dropdown lists that allow multiple selection. But these dropdown lists are allowing the same option being chosen. How can I change this behaviour without using v-model (since I'm creating these lists dynamically)?

Options:

```
 "categories": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Math",
      "years": [
        { "id": 14, "name": "4" },
        { "id": 15, "name": "5" },
        { "id": 16, "name": "6" }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "Science",
      "years": [
        { "id": 11, "name": "1" },
        { "id": 12, "name": "2" },
        { "id": 13, "name": "3" }
      ]
    }
  ]
```

HTML:

```
  <div
    v-for="category in categories">
    <label>{{category.name}}</label>
    <vue-select
      :options="category.years"
      label="name"
      @input="onCategoryYearSelect"
      multiple>
    </vue-select>
  </div>
```

Comment: Can you describe your problem more specifically?

Comment: The code above is working, and it allows multiple selection. But the problem is that it's allowing the same option being selected over and over again.

Comment: Oh, i see now. Can you provide your `onCategoryYearSelect` method?

Comment: Currently the `onCategroyYearSelect` method doesn't do anything. I'm only using it to log the input event.

Comment: Have you defined property where do you want to store selected years of categories?

Comment: No, I haven't defined where to store the selected values. I'm creating these separate vue-select dropdown lists so I'm not sure how to create the properties.

Comment: You have two choices: either define in in current object or define it in new data property (for example `selectedYears`), which will contain selected years of category. Which one should I use to write an answer?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by defining it in the current object. But I'm open to seeing what a solution would look like. I tried to use a v-model on a data property but because the categories are dynamically created, I couldn't get it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off you should define data property, where you will store you selected years.

It will be an object, which keys will be categories id's, and values will be selected years.

Then you should handle `<vue-select>` `@input` event, to set selected year to appropriate category.

```js
Vue.component('vue-select', VueSelect.VueSelect)

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      "selectedYears": {},
      "categories": [{
          "id": 1,
          "name": "Math",
          "years": [{
              "id": 14,
              "name": "4"
            },
            {
              "id": 15,
              "name": "5"
            },
            {
              "id": 16,
              "name": "6"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "id": 2,
          "name": "Science",
          "years": [{
              "id": 11,
              "name": "1"
            },
            {
              "id": 12,
              "name": "2"
            },
            {
              "id": 13,
              "name": "3"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  },
   methods: {
    inputHandler(id, e) {
      if (this.selectedYears[id] && this.selectedYears[id].find(item => item.id === e.id)) return;
      
      this.$set(this.selectedYears, id, e);
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-select@latest"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/vue-select@latest/dist/vue-select.css">
<div id="app">
  <div>
    <div v-for="category in categories" :key="category.id">
      <label>{{ category.name }}</label>
      <vue-select :options="category.years" label="name" multiple @input="inputHandler(category.id, $event)">
      </vue-select>
    </div>
    <h1>{{ selectedYears }}</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't know why this is not working for me, I'm still able to input duplicate options. What part of the code is making sure that duplicates are not allowed?

Comment: It's `<vue-select>`'s library area of responsibility.

Comment: That means you can select `2` multiple times?)

Comment: Do your categories update when change the value? I can write checking, that will prevent duplicates.

Comment: Yes, I select `1`, then `2`, then I'm able to select `1` again.